# Float values in an API

Tags: python, flask

I created a Flask API and I need a float value as an input. I am using postman to test that API but when I input 9.99, it doesn't see it as a float. How can I directly input a float into the request. For anyone wondering, I am going to work with a price of an item, and that needs to have a float value.

I am checking if the value is a float in the python code itself to make sure there is a valid input before passing it on to a database. Is there maybe another way to tackle this problem that I am missing here?

This is the code I am using for checking the type of the input:

```
if len(request.args["price"]) > 0:
        if type(request.args) == float: #The type of the argument should be float, so if future me is reading this, this is probably the cause of your error.
            productPrice = request.args["price"]
        else:
            return "<p>The second argument provided (product price) is not of the type 'Float'. Please provide a valid argument</p>"
    else:
        return "<p>Please provide a second argument (product price)</p>"
```

Comment: Are you using only flask or any other REST framework along with it like flask-restful or flask-restplus?

Answer (score 1):

Every argument passed in request.args will be str. If you need float, you need to convert it by yourself while getting the parameter `request.args.get("a", type=float)`

But if I could recommend you something (which is a common practice) - much easier is to store price in minors - so basically multiply it by 100 (or 10000 for some countries). That way you can use int in calculations which is much nicer to work with. However conversion from str is still needed.